# Convert eps figure to grayscale without removing white space around the figure

Tags: graphics, conversion, eps

I use eps2eps command followed by pscol command which convert color eps to grayscale. But this combination remove white space around the figure (which is probably done by eps2eps command). Directly applying pscol on my original figure without eps2eps before does not work.

How to convert eps color figure into gray scale to have the same white space around?

Comment: Do you have a lot of images that need to be processed in this way? I ask because this can easily be done manually, but that's obviously no good if you have hundreds of images.

Comment: I have about 20 images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The white space around images stored in `eps` format is controlled by the bounding box and high resolution bounding box definitions, which appear near the top of the file, and look like this.

```
%%BoundingBox: 1 0 388 327
%%HiResBoundingBox: 1.100000 0.800000 387.249609 326.700000
```

For a small number of images, you can just open the files with a text editor and replace the bounding box definitions in the version produced by `eps2eps` with the definitions from the old file.  Sometimes the high resolution bounding box will be absent, in which case just ignore this part and restore the bounding box to its original form.

Comment: I can change this numbers in version produced by `eps2eps` and it works. But, I cannot open original eps file with text editor to see original numbers.

Comment: @Petar --- why not?

Comment: For example with gedit: `gedit has not been able to detect the character encoding.Please check that you are not trying to open a binary file.` Only the version produced by `eps2eps` I can open with gedit.

Comment: @Petar --- that's weird. Can you make the file available for download and add a link to your question?

Comment: I menage to open with different text editor and solve the problem. The original file has some unreadable header, which is probably the reason why gedit detects this file as binary.

Comment: @Petar --- indeed, some applications put garbage at the start (and sometimes also the end) of `eps` files. The first line should be something like `%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0`; anything before that can be deleted. This garbage may be the reason why `pscol` doesn't work without `eps2eps`. What program is generating the original `eps` files?

Comment: I generate `eps` files with `OriginPro 8`. Yes, there is garbage at the start before this line and also in the end of file after `%%EOF`.

Comment: @Petar --- I don't know anything about `OriginPro`, but if it's anything like `Mathematica` in this respect, there may be an option/command to export `eps` for use by other applications. This might avoid the production of the garbage in the first place.

Comment: I didn't see such option in `Origin` when I exported pictures. It is not like `Mathematica`. Also, `eps` pictures I generate with `Mathematica` do not have this problem with garbage.